# how to handel submitted gravity form which contains singel file

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

i created a simple gravity form (id = 11) which contains 2 fields:

1. text field type (name = "my_name")
2. fileupload type (i could't set the name for it)

and there is the code i want to use for handel this form after submitation. how to change this snippet for handeling submited file?
**Please suppose I have to do the manual handling of the form myself**

```
$input_1 = $_POST['myname'];


//how to get sbmitted file?
//$file = ?


$array_of_inputs = array("input_1" => $input_1 , "file_name" => $file);


$gravity_submit_result = submit_in_gravity_form(11 , $array_of_inputs , $api_key , $private_key ,$web_url); 
if ($gravity_submit_result){
    $response['message'] = $body['response'];
    $response['status'] = 'ok';
}
else{
    $response['status'] = false;
}
exit(json_encode($response));}
```

[this page contains my gravity form](http://maskanmui-ac.ir/test2/)

Comment: You want to save in input textbox value which is in gravity form

Comment: @Jinesh i want to save both (textbox) and (file)

Comment: You want to save gravity form data right

Comment: @Jinesh yes this is true

Comment: @Jinesh do your code save the submitted file? in the form there is two fields (text and file type). Please keep in mind i created html form dynamicaly and i could't Assign the name for file

Comment: Yes my code is working

Answer (score 0):

For solve this issue you can follow this code

```
  add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );
        function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {

            //if the Advanced Post Creation add-on is used, more than one post may be created for a form submission
            //the post ids are stored as an array in the entry meta
            $created_posts = gform_get_meta( $entry['id'], 'gravityformsadvancedpostcreation_post_id' );
            foreach ( $created_posts as $post )
            {
                $post_id = $post['post_id'];
                $post = get_post( $post_id );
              require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
              require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
              require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
              $attach_id = media_handle_upload('file', $post_id);
              if (is_numeric($attach_id)) {
                 update_option('option_image', $attach_id);
                 update_post_meta($post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id);
}
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'myname', $_POST['myname'];);
            }
        }
```